# MySQLi Insert Statement unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I can not for the life of me figure out why PHP is complaining about the following:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING`

Code:

```
while($row = $rbh->fetchAssoc($rbhSQL)) {
   $statsSQL = $stats->query("INSERT INTO usage (user, grp, type, size, blocks, count, filesystem) VALUES ($row['owner'], $row['gr_name'], $row['type], $row['size'], $row['blocks'], $row['count'], \"$fsName\") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE size=$row['size'], blocks=$row['blocks'], count=$row->['count']");
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When injecting variables into a string, array values are referred to [without single quotes around the key](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#example-79).

This would be valid:

```
... VALUES ($row[owner], $row[gr_name], ...
```

However, what would be *preferable* is to use a [parameterized query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496) instead, which has numerous benefits:

- ensures your application is safe from SQL injection (can even happen inadvertently when the data is under your control)
- makes the query more readable
- sidesteps this issue entirely

If this were something other than an SQL query I would still recommend using `sprintf` instead of directly injecting all these variables.